# Deploy go app to docker in vagrant

Tags: go, docker, vagrant

Now i'm working on RESTfull API on go, using Windows and goclipse. 
Testing environemnt consists of few VMs managed by Vagrant. These machines contain nginx, PostgreSQL etc. The app should be deployed into Docker on the separated VM.

There is no problem to deploy app on first time using guide like here: https://blog.golang.org/docker. I've read a lot of information and guides but still totally confused how to automate deploying process and update go app in docker after some changes in code done. On the current stage changes in code done very often, so deploying should be fast.

Could you please advise me with correct way to setup some kind of local CI for such case? What approach will be better?
Thanks a lot.